# Bash grep local IP address and write to file in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, ifconfig

I'm trying to get my local ip with ifconfig and write it to file but for some reason fail to do so.

```
run:
    LOCALIP=$(shell ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $1}') &
    echo "var LOCAL_IP = '${LOCALIP}'" > local_ip.js &
```

It does get the correct IP but for some reason fails to write it to file and file contains only `var LOCAL_IP = ''`

Could anyone help me and tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't run the commands in the background. `LOCALIP` is being set in a subshell, and so not assigned to in the shell that writes to `local_ip.js`.

Comment: Can you provide an expected output?

Comment: @chepner Could you fix my code - not to run in subshell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues: one, each separate command in a Makefile recipe is executed in a separate shell, so you need to "merge" them. Two, you need to double the `$` in the echo so that it is sent to the shell, not expanded first by `make`. This should work:

```
run:
        LOCALIP=$(shell ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $1}'); \
        echo "var LOCAL_IP = '$${LOCALIP}'" > local_ip.js
```

The semicolon and the line-continuation backslash ensure that the entire recipe is executed in the same shell, so that `LOCALIP` is still set when the `echo` is run. You could "simplify" this by embedding the command substitution directly in the argument to `echo`.

```
run:
        echo "var LOCAL_IP = '$(shell ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $1}')'" > local_ip.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk can work:

```
ifconfig | awk -F: '/inet addr/&& !($2 ~ /127\.0\.0\.1/){gsub(/ .*/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

Comment: It's not the greping for ip not working, it is writing to file

Comment: You can just add `> output.log` to store its output.